# ngrx effect dispatch action error and null when passing action payload

Tags: angular, httpclient, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I have this effect that dispatches a dummy action if the final post succeeds.

```js
@Effect() post$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
        .ofType(PropertyActions.UPLOAD_FILE_GETSIGNEDURL)
        .switchMap((action: PropertyActions.UploadFileGetsignedUrl) => {
            this.actionData = action.payload;
            return this.authService.getAuthenticatedUser().getSession((err, session) => {
                if (err) {
                return;
                }

                // post to API gateway
                return this.httpClient.post('https://abcd.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/', {
                    title: 'foo',
                    body: 'bar',
                    userId: 1
                    })
                    .pipe(map(res => {
                            console.log("res from signed url: " + res);
                            this.httpClient.post(res.toString(), this.actionData)
                            .pipe(map(res => {
                                console.log("res from upload: " + res);
                                return new PropertyActions.OpenAllProperties(res);
                            }))
                            //return new PropertyActions.OpenAllProperties(res);
                        },
                        err => {
                            console.log("Error occured");
                            return new PropertyActions.OpenAllProperties(null);
                        })
                    );
                }
            )
        }
    )
```

But 2 things that are wrong:

1. I get this error: ERROR Error: Effect "PropertyEffects.post$" dispatched an invalid action: undefined
   core.js:1427 ERROR TypeError: Actions must be objects
   This error is generated in the console after step past the inner most post: this.httpClient.post(res.toString(), this.actionData).
   Also note the inner console.log never gets hit
2. I am trying to pass the action.payload of the first callback into the inner most post but get null. this.actionData is a variable of the Component I set using:

```js
@Injectable()
export class PropertyEffects {

    private actionData: string;

    constructor(
        private actions$: Actions,
        private httpClient: HttpClient,
        private store: Store<fromApp.AppState>,
        private authService: AuthService
    ){}

    @Effect() post$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
    ...
```

How to pass the action.payload through to the inner most post?
Thank you in advance for your help! I am new to Angular and Rxjs so appreciate your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not clutter your effects in this way bad for testing and reuse, try to remove the HTTP call to a service and inject then use it in your effect.
lets say you placed it in MyHttpService like so

```
@Injectable()
export class MyHttpService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }        

  addItem(payload: AddItemPayload): Observable<AddItemSuccessPayload> {  
    return this.http.post<AddItemSuccessPayload>('/api/items/' + payload.id, payload.Data).pipe(
      map((data) => {
        return {item: data.item};
      })
    );
  }
}
```

now we inject it in the effect and pass action.payload through to the inner  the service if error or success we dispatch it to other effects

```
 @Injectable()
 export class VendorEffect {

  @Effect() 
  addItem$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(Vendor.ActionType.ADD_ITEM),
    map((action: Vendor.AddItem) => action.payload),
    exhaustMap((request) =>
      this.myHttpService.addItem(request).pipe(
        map(payload => new Vendor.AddItemSuccess(payload)),
        catchError(err => of(new Vendor.AddItemFail(err)))
      )
    )
  );


      constructor(private actions$: Actions, private myHttpService: MyHttpService) {
      }

    }
```

Thats abut it and this is the method used now with ngrx using pipes with ofType

Comment: is there a reason you have to wrap the catchError in an observable.of?

Comment: This effect is re-dispatching, so you need to return an observable in the end even if an error occurs which will be caught by catchError and its return type must be wrapped by an of() for it to work. Errors not caught in effects will cause ngrx to silently stop working

Answer (score 0):

In the original question,

the innermost post: `this.httpClient.post(res.toString(), this.actionData)` might be returning either `undefined` or empty. Angular Effect expects you to handle such situations by returning an action. You can do so as following:

```
return new ErrorAction({msg: "Data could not be loaded"})
```

In your `ErrorAction`:

```
export class ErrorAction implements Action {
    readonly type = ActionTypes.ErrorAction;
    msg: String;
    constructor(error: any) {
        this.msg = error.msg;
    }
}
```

And, finally subscribe to the `ErrorAction` type and display the error message. You can make use of `NotificationsService` as follows:

```
this.actions.pipe(ofType(ActionType.ErrorAction)).subscribe((error: any) => {
    this.notificationService.error(error.msg);
});
```